# How to extract a string that matches with the same string with period(.) before it? (Only using Regular expressions)

Tags: javascript

if I have a string like this `"this is a .period _test string"`. If I match `"_test"` then It should return me `"test"` and If i match `".period"` it should return me `"period"`.

Comment: They easiest way but slightly hacky would be to remove '.' and '_' from the search result. Just replace it with nothing -- if you need more logic, you could check only the first character of the resulting string. It depends on how far you want to go.

Comment: i want it to be done only using regular expressions

Comment: by the question's title it looks like you are wondering if it can be done only using Regular expressions, that is, it looks like you are asking for an alternative to regex

Answer (score 0):

Look for `.period` or `_test`. Then remove the `.` or `_` using substring.

```
  var regex = /(.period|_test)/gi; 
  var string = 'this is a .period _test string';
  var matches;

  while ((matches = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (matches.index === regex.lastIndex) {
       regex.lastIndex++;
   }
  console.log(matches[0].substring(1,matches[0].length));
  }
```

Comment: I want to match using .period and _test but not just "." and "
_"

Comment: I had updated the answer long back is this what you wanted?